# How do the Weyl spinors differ from dotted and undotted spinors?

Tags: notation, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-equation, spinors

As asked in the title, how do the Weyl spinors $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ and $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ differ from dotted and undotted spinors?

Comment: The two examples you give are the fundamental dotted and undotted spinors.

Comment: What do you mean by _fundamental_ here?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409156/